# angularjs: How to set the value of a kendo color picker inside kendo template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I have the following rowTemplate for my kendo grid:

```
<script id="gridTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<tr data-uid="#= uid #">
    <td>
        <input type="color" kendo-color-picker k-palette="controller.colors" value="'#=color#'" on-change="controller.changeColor()" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that I want to set the value of the color picker from the `dataItem.color` property. With the syntax above I get the following message: 
`The specified value "'#0000ff'" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "#rrggbb" where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal numbers.`

If I change it to `value="#=color#"` (without the single quotes) then I get:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-    0 [#] in expression [#00ff00].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%23%5D&p2=%2300ff00
Cause: <input type="color" kendo-color-picker="" k-palette="trend.colors" value="#00ff00" on-change="trend.changeColor()">
{anonymous}()@columns 0-0 [#] in expression [#00ff00].
{anonymous}() (http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/)$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%23%5D&p2=%2300ff00
```

I tried to move the template in the angular code and use `function(dataItem)` but resulted with the same errors. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error when trying to set the Value field. Instead, I tried to set the view model/$scope property that represents the color palette.

Kendo Color Picker control

```
        <input kendo-color-picker ng-model="dashboardBuilder.templateOptions.titleBackgroundColor" k-palette="'websafe'" k-preview="false" k-input="true" k-opacity="true"/>
```

On the load event of the controller set the color palette's property as so

```
 vm.templateOptions = {
            titleBackgroundColor: '#000000'
        };
```

That will default your picker to your color of choice.